# Handler Affecting all Rows on First Button Clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a table of users and include a reset password link on each row.

When I click the first button in my table (each row has that button), it hits my handler (which lives in my container...my container passes the handler down as a prop) it's hitting my handler `handleResetPassword`.

*But* when `setState()` in `handleResetPassword` is called after the try/catch, it updates state which means my lower-level components get notified of that state.  Since I'm updating it saying there's an error for some reason though all rows's  sees that updated state and therefore every button on each row ends up showing the . I only want the button I clicked to show it, not all:

**UserContainer.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import * as UserAsyncActions from '../actions/Users/UserAsyncActions'
import Users from '../components/Users/UserList'

class UsersContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      resetPasswordError: null
    }

    this.handleResetPassword = this.handleResetPassword.bind(this)
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.allUsers(this.props.token)
  }

  async handleResetPassword(uuid) {

    // console.log(e.current.target)
    console.log("handleResetPassword invoked!")
    try {
      await this.props.resetUserPassword()
      if(this.props.hasResetPassword){
        // show successful message (set message here)
        return
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      this.setState({
        resetEmailValidationState: 'error',
        resetPasswordError: !this.state.hasResetPassword && 'reset failed'
      })
    }

    this.setState({
      resetEmailValidationState: 'error',
      resetPasswordError: !this.state.hasResetPassword &&
      'reset failed'
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Users
        handleResetPassword={this.handleResetPassword}
        resetPasswordError={this.state.resetPasswordError}
        users={this.props.users}
      />)
  }

}
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isRequestingAllUsers: state.user.isRequestingAllUsers,
  hasResetPassword: state.user.hasResetPassword,
  users: state.user.users,
  token: state.auth.token
})

export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  allUsers: UserAsyncActions.allUsers,
  resetUserPassword: UserAsyncActions.resetPasssord
}

export { Users }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UsersContainer)
```

**UserList.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { HelpBlock, Button, Table } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class Users extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<span><UserList {...this.props} /></span>)
  }
}

export class UserList extends Component {
  render(){
    const { handleResetPassword, users, resetPasswordError } = this.props
    const userList = users && users.map(
      (user) =>
        <User
          handleResetPassword={handleResetPassword}
          key={user.uuid}
          resetPasswordError={resetPasswordError}
          user={user}
        />)

    return(<Table responsive >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>uuid</th>
          <th>First</th>
          <th>Last</th>
          <th>email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{userList}</tbody>
    </Table>)
  }
}

export class User extends Component {
  render() {
    const { handleResetPassword } = this.props,
      { uuid, firstName, lastName, email } = this.props.user

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{uuid}</td>
        <td>{firstName}</td>
        <td>{lastName}</td>
        <td>{email}</td>
        <td>
          <HelpBlock disabled={this.props.resetPasswordError ? true : false}>{this.props.resetPasswordError}</HelpBlock>
          <Button onClick={() => handleResetPassword(uuid)}>
            reset password
          </Button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

Notice how after I click the first button, handleResetPassword is hit, and in it I'm setting state:

this.setState({
          resetEmailValidationState: 'error',
          resetPasswordError: !this.state.hasResetPassword &&
          'reset failed'
        })

Well, now each button's  ends up showing the error message instead of just showing it for the first button I clicked:

[image]

**Here's a [screencast of it happening](https://youtu.be/Fj64p4lJN1o)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state that controls the props of the button is passed to your `<Users />` component, which then passes that same prop to `<UserList />`, which then passes the same prop again to every `<User />`. When you click a button it changes the state in your `<UsersContainer />`, causing the resetPasswordError prop to change in all buttons.

You'll need to give each button an index within the container's state to toggle individually or have a container for each `<User />`.

EDIT:

Ok so I would create a container component for your `<UserList />` with connect. Map your `handleResetPassword` method to dispatch the resetPassword action. ( You should extract this action and you'll have to write the reducer. ) The idea here keep a reference to all users in the UserList, and on each user have a resetPasswordError property that is null unless there is an error. If there's an error, use the `handleResetPassword` method to dispatch an action with the user's uuid. In the reducer you can update the state of the user. Here is some code as an example.

```
const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    return {
        users: state.users
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = ( dispatch ) => {
    return {
        handleResetPassword: ( uuid ) => {
            dispatch({
                type: "RESET_USER_PASSWORD",
                uuid
            })
        }
    };
};

let UserList = ({ users, handleResetPassword }) => {
    const userList = users && users.map(
        ( user ) => (
            <User
                key={ user.uuid }
                user={ user }
                handleResetPassword={ handleResetPassword }
                resetPasswordError={ user.resetPasswordError }
            />
        )
    ); 

    return(
        <Table responsive >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>uuid</th>
                    <th>First</th>
                    <th>Last</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{ userList }</tbody>
        </Table>
    );
};
export UserList = connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps )( UserList );

export const User = ({ user, resetPasswordError, handleResetPassword }) => {
    const { uuid, firstName, lastName, email } = props.user;
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{ uuid }</td>
            <td>{ firstName }</td>
            <td>{ lastName }</td>
            <td>{ email }</td>
            <td>
                <HelpBlock disabled={ resetPasswordError ? true : false }>
                    { resetPasswordError }
                </HelpBlock>
                <Button onClick={ () => handleResetPassword( uuid ) }>
                    reset password
                </Button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
};
```

Comment: can you show an example in code, I get what you're saying but...I don't understand how my handler works with each index

Comment: what do you mean by ` index within the container's state`

Comment: I don't have a need to work with the index in my handler (such as uuid as I'm passing...I only passed it to try and figure out how to resolve my problem but I don't actually use uuid anywhere in my hendler) meaning if I pass an index I don't see how I'd just show the error for just that one button

Comment: Unfortunately it's 3am here and I'm heading to bed so no code examples until tomorrow :( The issue runs a little more deep than how your state is updating. The whole data flow of the components needs some attention. One thing you really should address is using a class only to use a render lifecycle hook. That should be a function stateless component. I will try to help you more when I wake up if your problem has not been resolved.

Comment: So I just don't know a way to do this honestly.  I know the way I am doing isn't quite right like you said with the flow

Comment: Alright, I will try to help you out. I just noticed you are using redux in this project as well. If you're using redux you should not be explicitly setting state in a component. Let me work on something and I'll post soonish.

Comment: I got it working...I will post it..and maybe you'll have an even better suggestion.  Let me update my original post and add an Update section